# shown last Category (Date) as title in amcharts

Tags: amcharts

I tried to Find Solution in Amchart for Shown Last Category(Date) in Title
I'm Using Dataloader and load json file in amcharts
shown last Category (Date) as title in amcharts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`complete`](https://github.com/amcharts/dataloader/#user-content-using-callback-functions) callback in the dataloader to make modifications to your chart object at the end of the load. For example:

```
  dataLoader: {
    url: "/path/to/endpoint",
    complete: function(chart) {
      chart.addTitle(
        "Data from " +
          chart.dataProvider[0][chart.categoryField] +
          " to " +
          chart.dataProvider[chart.dataProvider.length - 1][
            chart.categoryField
          ],
        16,
        "#444444",
        1,
        true
      );
    }
  },
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/72e0f2f2791365912692b5f5903cf266?editors=0010)